# Cent OS password rules not working

Tags: centos, password, pam

I wanted to set password rules for all users like min and max length , 1 digit and so on. So I modified /etc/pam.d/system-auth as below

```
password    required     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 difok=4
```

but its not working, so just to give a try i have modified /etc/pam.d/cs-auth as

```
password    required     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 difok=4
```

and

password-auth as

```
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so  try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 difok=4
```

But none of them seems to be working. I have attached snap of respective pam.d files
[image]

[image]

/etc/pam.d/passwd contents

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      cs-auth
account    include      cs-auth
password   substack     cs-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CentOS 7 you need to modify  /etc/security/pwquality.conf , it supersedes cracklib. Just uncomment the lines you want to use.

Full info see `man pwquality.conf`

Comment: its cent OS 6.9

Comment: @user530158 OK, can you add the content of your /etc/pam.d/passwd file?

Comment: updated question with /etc/pam.d/passwd contents